# javascript - Change text color multiple times between two color ranges

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, textcolor

I was wondering if someone could help me change the color of the text multiple times then form color #627CA9 to #FFFFFF and vice versa.

I Tried this:

```js
function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#627CA9")
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#FFFFFF"
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#627CA9"; // forecolor
  }

}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">CHVRCHES</div>
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid2'); return false;" id="myid2" class="centered">PVRIS</div>
```

The code only changes the color 1 time.

(Sorry my english)

Thanks

Comment: So do you want to constantly change the color?

Comment: So it works for `myid1` but not for `myid2`?

Comment: yes, multiple times

Comment: does not work at all, only changes to #FFFFFF

Comment: you should compare with `==` not `=`. By using `=` the result of the `if` is always `true`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That is not the only problem, In some browsers the color is converted to rgb, thus the check wouldnt work either way

Comment: @RobinZigmond Flagging for a duplicate would make more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you're assigning the colour with "`=`" instead of checking it with "`==`", the colour is also being set as RGB. Checking against this seems to work;

```js
function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (x.style.color != "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    x.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  else {
    x.style.color = "#627CA9"; // forecolor
  }

}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">CHVRCHES</div>
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid2'); return false;" id="myid2" class="centered">PVRIS</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `document.getElementById(id).style.color = "#627CA9"` change it to `document.getElementById(id).style.color == "#627CA9"`, Also you should be using classes and change the name of the class

```js
function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className === "white") x.className = "";
  else x.className = "white";
}
```

```css
div {
  color: #627CA9;
}

.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">CHVRCHES</div>
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor('myid2'); return false;" id="myid2" class="centered">PVRIS</div>
```

You can also do the action automatically with CSS

```css
@keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    color: #627CA9;
  }
  50% {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  100% {
    color: #627CA9;
  }
}

.change-color {
  animation-name: color-change;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="change-color">CHVRCHES</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare values, not assign them. In the condition put two equal signs.

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.color == "#627CA9")
```

UPD: In addition, usually when setting color using javascript, it is converted to RGB, so further comparison with HEX is no longer possible. You will have to compare and set the values in RGB, but this is not good practice. The best solution would be to create an additional class and styling it through CSS, which will allow you to check the presence of a class on an element and, based on this, remove or add this class.